# How do I adjust kerning in my section macros

Tags: macros, sectioning, microtype, kerning

How do I insert `\textls` in my section macros to apply the kerning defined in my `\microtype` command?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 100]{microtype}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{18pt}{23.4}\selectfont}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}    
    
\section{Sample Section}
words words words

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last mandatory argument of `\titleformat` can end with a one-parameter macro.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[tracking = true, letterspace = 100]{microtype}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{18pt}{23.4}\selectfont}{}{0em}{\textls}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample Section}
words words words

\end{document}
```

I added `fix-cm` in order to avoid a wealth of warnings.

[image]

Remember that *anyone who would letterspace lower case would steal sheep*.